# Database Triggers vs Controller Triggers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, triggers, historical-db

I have a table that I expose to users for edition on a rails website.

This table needs to have a way to keep track of changes and at the same time needs to be available for reporting purposes.

I ditched triggers for this functionality because they don't leave any trace of activity and they're difficult to maintain. My alternative is to implement the trigger in the insertion/edition controller, but I think this solution is cumbersome as well, so, any alternatives?

Comment: look at PaperTrail gem: https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail

Comment: Looks promising, trying...